# How do I call a callback from the arguments array?

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

I understand how to call a callback normally, but when I try to call a callback using the arguments array it doesn't work. Here is code for how it is normally:

```
function someFunc(parameter1, callback){
  alert(parameter1);
  callback.call();
}

someFunc('Hello', function(){
  alert('World!');
});
```

And the exact same format using the arguments array, which doesn't work.

```
function someFunc(parameter1){
  alert(parameter1);
  arguments[arguments.length-1].call();
}

someFunc('Hello', function(){
  alert('World!');
});
```

What is going on here?

Comment: It's [working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/xKSfD/) in FF and IE8 - What browser are you using?

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Ok I'm using Chrome and I downloaded a patch and it works now. Thanks for helping me haha. I was so baffled. :)

Comment: Heh, random Chrome bug apparently..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no errors whatsoever and should work fine on its own. This example shows that it is working perfectly. -- http://jsfiddle.net/FDT8N/